# What's cleanest way to have nested map get calls in scala

Tags: scala

In Scala I need to call get an object from a map, based on a key that I get from another map. The 'Java' was to it would be:

```
map1.get(map2.get(topic).get) // Could throw java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

But this doesn't really seem like the Scala way. What would be the Scala way of doing this?

Answer (score 6):

Use a for-comprehension.

```
for {
  m2 <- map2.get(topic)
  m1 <- map1.get(m2)
} yield {
  m1
}
```

This desugars to:

```
map2.get(topic).flatMap(map1.get)
```

Answer (score 0):

If both lookups can fail and you don't care which you can use `Option.flatMap`:

```
map2.get(topic).flatMap(m1.get(_))
```